# STM32 Series Microcontroller - Calculations of Timer Variables

Tags: microcontroller

This is a subject that seems to have a lot of confusion (I do not fully understand). How to calculate the Variables:

- Period
- Prescaler
- Duration

if only a few other variables are known. At higher frequencies, for example 1000000Hz simple rules work. At lower Frequencies like 1281Hz things get a little more complicated.

As an example: if we aim for an output frequency of 1281Hz, we need to set the ARR Register to: 32785. We need to set the PSC Register to: 3 and if we want a 50% DutyCycle, we need to set the CCRx Register to: 16393. Where the x in CCRx is the specified Channel one is going to use. 1, 2, 3 or 4.

The Registers need to see values of 16 BITs, Integer Values(65535 or less).

Equations exist so calculations can be made, for example:

\$TIM_{Update Frequency(Hz)} = \frac{Clock}{(PSC - 1) * (Period - 1)}\$

\$1281.11273792094 = \frac{84000000}{3 * 32785} \$

now, the problem becomes more complicated, for a desired frequency of 840Hz:

\$425.946209078739 = \frac{84000000}{167 * 1189}\$

Here in lies the problem, how does one find the value of PSC when one knows only the values for "Clock" and "Period"? The value "TIM_Update_Frequency(Hz)" is not always the actual Desired Frequency.

Other equations must exist so as to calculate the "PSC" Value, or to calculate the "TIM_Update_Frequency(Hz)" so as to deduce the other values.

Guess work is just not a logical approach here.

Can anyone help with more equations for solving for the other variables?

Thank you

Chris

Comment: A couple of points. 1. Numbers usually have a character every 3 digits, to make it easier to parse. For example, 1000000Hz, using the GB/USA-English convention is easier to read written as 1,000,000Hz, or elsewhere 1 000 000Hz (or even 1_000_000). 2. There are [SI unit Metric prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) so 1000000Hz is easier to understand when it is written as 1MHz. 3. A typical crystal, used as the frequency source of an STM32, is accurate to 20 parts in 1 million or worse (2 in 100,000), so quoting numbers like 1281.11273792094, is misleading; 1281.11 is enough.

Comment: @gblumer - Yes I understand what your points are. However, many Function Generators do have 4 or 6 digit resolutions after the decimal point, expensive ones can have more. A nice example of this: http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Hantek-HDG2002B-2-Channels-16Bits-250MSa-s-Function-Arbitrary-Waveform-Generator-/141393639392?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item20ebb7b7e0I put the numbers in after the decimal points really just to show that I was not messing with the numbers generated. Thank you, helpful post: +1.

Comment: That link leads to a http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Hantek-HDG2002B-2-Channels-16Bits-250MSa-s-Function-Arbitrary-Waveform-Generator-/141393639392?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item20ebb7b7e0I device which says "Accuracy:±2ppm". It matters less where the decimal point is, and more how many significant figures are used. So "±2ppm" is only one more digit than a typical crystal, i.e. not 1281.11273792094 but only 1281.113.

Comment: I don’t understand the question, how can you know the period register value without knowing the prescalar value? The prescaler is to help achieve longer timer periods. Normally you start with a known system/peripheral clock and a desired timer frequency you then need to deduce the prescaler and timer period register values, is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have deleted my last answer because it was not correct all of the time. I have managed to use this equation to get correct results:

```
Prescaler = ((((ClockSpeed) / ((period) / (1 / frequency))) + 0.5) - 1);
```

Factoring Numbers was not the answer.

Here is a simple method I am now using to work out the other variables, Period and Duration.

```
private void CalculateVariables()
    {
        // Set the Bus Speed (APB1 or APB2), all timers are APB1 except TIM1 and TIM8...
        if (PWMPin == CPU.Pin.Pin7_X3 || PWMPin == CPU.Pin.Pin9_X3 || PWMPin == CPU.Pin.Pin7_X4)
        {
            ClockSpeed = CPU.Clock.APB2;
        }
        else
        {
            ClockSpeed = CPU.Clock.APB1;
        }

        #region Fields...

        uint ONE_MHZ = 1000000;

        uint prescaler = 0;
        uint period = m_period;
        uint duration = m_duration;
        uint scale = ((uint)m_scale);

        // Scale in MHz... 
        uint scaleMHz = scale / ONE_MHZ;

        uint clk = ((uint)ClockSpeed / ONE_MHZ);

        if (duration > period) duration = period;

        #endregion

        #region Calculate Variables (This is a C# implimentation of GHI Source ("PWM_ApplyConfiguration"))...

        prescaler = clk / scale;

        if (prescaler == 0)
        {
            if (period > (0xFFFFFFFF / clk))
            {
                // Avoid Overflow... 
                prescaler = clk;
                period /= scaleMHz;
                duration /= scaleMHz;
            }
            else
            {
                prescaler = 1;
                period = period * clk / scaleMHz;
                duration = duration * clk / scaleMHz;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (prescaler > 0x10000)
            {
                // Prescaler too Large... 
                if (period >= 0x80000000) break;
                prescaler >>= 1;
                period <<= 1;
                duration <<= 1;
            }
        }

        bool TimerIs16Bit = true;

        // Were not using Timer 2 of Timer 5...
        if (TimerIs16Bit)
        {
            // All Timers are 16 bit Timer's except 2 and 5... 
            while (period >= 0x10000)
            {
                // period too large 
                if (prescaler > 0x8000) break;
                prescaler <<= 1;
                period >>= 1;
                duration >>= 1;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        if (debug)
        {
            Debug.Print("*** Scale *******");
            // Print to Debug window new config...
            Debug.Print("Period = " + period);
            Debug.Print("Prescaler = " + PrescalerFromPeriodFrequencyAndClock(period, this.Frequency));
            Debug.Print("Duration = " + duration);
        }

        ARRValue = (period - 1);
        PSCValue = PrescalerFromPeriodFrequencyAndClock(period, this.Frequency);
        CCRxValue = duration;
    }
```

a Simple static Class CPU and I have added:

```
public enum Pin : int
    {
        Pin7_X3 = 1,
        Pin8_X3 = 2,
        Pin9_X3 = 3,
        Pin7_X4 = 4,
        Pin8_X4 = 5,
        Pin9_X4 = 6
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the clock, prescaler and auto reload, repetition counter (if present) parameters, the 16-bit timer can generate an update event from a nanosecond to a few minutes.

For example, to generate an event two times per second, choose
Clock frequency(TIM_CLK) = 168 Mhz,
Prescalar(PSC) = 16799,
Period(ARR) = 4999,
repetition counter(RCR) = 0,

then the 16-bit timer will generate an event two times per second.

[image]

For more information ;

[STM32 Timer Overview](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/54/0f/67/eb/47/34/45/40/DM00042534.pdf/files/DM00042534.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00042534.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool written in python to do all the calculations: https://github.com/v0idv0id/STM32-Scaler